# Why do programs with arguments passed in argc and argv get different results when executed in different ways

Tags: c, linux, argv, argc, execl

```
void main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
     for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
     {
         printf("%s ", argv[i]);
     }
}
```

when I use command `./test 1 2 3` in terminal to execute this program, I got result `./test 1 2 3` ,but when I use function `execl("/usr/src/test", "1", "2", "3", NULL)` in another program I got result
`1 2 3`,why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of `execl()` is:

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg0, ..., /*, (char *)0, */);
```

So you have

```
path = "/usr/src/test"
arg0 = "1"
arg1 = "2"
arg3 = "3"
```

The `argN` parameters are put into the `argv` array of the new process.

You have to repeat the path as `arg0` to put that into `argv[0]`.

```
execl("/usr/src/test", "/usr/src/test", "1", "2", "3", NULL)
```

This isn't done automatically because `argv[0]` isn't required to be the same as the program path, and there are some situations where it isn't (for instance, login shells are invoked by adding a `-` prefix in `argv[0]`).

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for exec() family of functions:

It is explained there as follows:

The  const  char *arg  and  subsequent  ellipses  in the execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.  Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to  null-terminated  strings that represent the argument list available to the executed program.  **The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.**  The list  of  arguments must be terminated by a null pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.